# using ajax call to post to db

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to submit premiseID & applicationID to db using ajax call. Im getting current premiseID from viewModel & applicationID from a dropdown-menu. However, it is not submitting to db. On the backend im using requestModel method with a request body

LinkApplicationToChecklist.cshtml

```
        <div class="mobile-desktop">
            <div id="selGroupState" class="input-group card-option-group-move-top">
                <label id="applicationId" class="card-label-top">
                    <img src="~/assets/img/myhome-file-icon.png" class="label-img-inline" />@Localizer.GetLocalizedString("HMO_LinkApplicationToChecklist_Application_Number")
                </label>
                <label id="ddlState" data-offset="0,-1" data-toggle="dropdown" data-flip="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="custom-select card-text-16 card-option-control text-truncate" onclick="dimResultAndBackgroundShowSearch()"></label>
                <div id="state-dropdown-mobile" class="display-dropdown special-drop dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-overlay card-dropdown-dashboard dropdown-round-radius" style="box-shadow: -4px 4px 16px 0 rgba(73, 73, 74, 0.16); width:100%;">
                    <div class="account-dropdown-list-2 ScrollStyle">
                        <ul id="ddlStateList" class="xlist-group manageAccountList" style="margin-right:5px; margin-left:-30px;">
                            @{
                                @foreach (var cotApplication in Model.COTApplicationNumbers)
                                {
                                    <li class="list-group-item accountListItem" dropdown-value="@cotApplication.ReferenceNo" dropdown-text="@cotApplication.ReferenceNo">
                                        <div class="list-group-item-title">
                                            <div class="list-border-bottom list-border-bottom mobile-font-16" style="margin-left:-5px; margin-top:2px;">
                                                @cotApplication.ReferenceNo
                                                <br>
                                                @cotApplication.CombinedAddress
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                }
                             }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="button-footer-sticky">
     <button type="submit" id="linkApplicationConfirm" class="mobile-btn mobile-btn-green" onclick="SubmitApplication()">@Localizer.GetLocalizedString("HMO_Confirm")</button>
</div>


 function SubmitApplication() 
 {
        var requestModel = {
            premiseID: "@Model.HMOPremiseDetails.PremisesID",
            applicationID: { applicationID: $("#ddlState").val() }
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("UpdateLinkApplicationToChecklist", "MyHomeChecklist", new { area ="Application" })",
            data: requestModel,
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Success!");
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("Error!");
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost("UpdateLinkApplicationToChecklist")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateLinkApplicationToChecklist(LinkApplicationToChecklistRequest requestModel)
    {
        try
        {

            var viewModel = await _hmoHelper.LinkApplicationToChecklistAsync(requestModel);
            return Json(new { status = "Success" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { status = "Error", errorMessage = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

LinkApplicationToChecklistRequest.cs

```
public class LinkApplicationToChecklistRequest
{
    public string PremisesID { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you set a breakpoint at the backend controller to see the value of `premiseID & applicationID` ? Besides, "it is not submitting to db" How do you pass them to db ?

Comment: im passing it using requestModel method

Comment: What 's your value of `requestModel` ? Could you share your model of LinkApplicationToChecklistRequest ?

Comment: ive shared the request model

Comment: So your problem is what ?

Comment: You can get the data" Im getting current premiseID from viewModel & applicationID from a dropdown-menu. " in your `UpdateLinkApplicationToChecklist(LinkApplicationToChecklistRequest requestModel)` ?

Comment: nope, tried to debug..it says null

Comment: You can get  ApplicationID? Or both of them are null ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253150/discussion-between-suraya-zulkifli-and-qing-guo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code

```
var requestModel = {
            premiseID: "@Model.HMOPremiseDetails.PremisesID",
            applicationID: { applicationID: $("#ddlState").val() }
        };
```

into

```
var requestModel = {
            PremisesID: "@Model.HMOPremiseDetails.PremisesID",
            ApplicationID: $("#ddlState").val()
        };
```